# Network error no matter if statement structure

Tags: javascript

I am writing a app that is using server side code mainly. But the errors are thrown no matter what ever with a correct connection. Please help.

```
function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        if (states[networkState]="Unknown connection")
        {
        alert('Get in a trusted Connection: ' + states[networkState]);
        }
        else if (states[networkState]="No network connection")
        {
        alert('Warning: ' + states[networkState]+': Please Get Connection and Reconnect');
        }
        else
        {
        var ref = window.open('http://70.61.212.124:8083', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
    }
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` compares two references, equals() checks for equality

Comment: @DoubleDouble You mean `===`

Comment: Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: my bad, thought my question list was sorted to 'Java' tags. Here is a good answer explaining for javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Anyway, when you'll get around those errors, I suggest you changing your state of mind. Creating an object and assigning it strings related to the connection type is superfluous. Why don't you just check the connection type? Something like `if (networkState === Connection.UNKNOWN)` etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

In your statement

```
 if (states[networkState]="Unknown connection")
            {
            alert('Get in a trusted Connection: ' + states[networkState]);
            }
```

you are assigning

```
states[networkState]="Unknown connection"
```

so value of

`states[networkState]` would always be `"Unknown connection"` and this `if` condition would always be true, as assignment always returns true.

i hope what you really mean to do is

```
states[networkState]=="Unknown connection"
```